# DynamoDB IN Query

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to make a Postgres or Mongo like IN query with DynamoDB.

Given I have a data structure like this:

```
{
    type: 'a' 
},
{
    type: 'b'
},
{
    type: 'c'
}
```

How can I scan for e.g. all 'a's and 'b's?

I've tried something like this:

```
docClient.scan({
    TableName: 'Exmaple',
    FilterExpression: 'type IN (:var)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':var': docClient.createSet(['a','b'])
    }
});
```

But it just returns nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help and assistance.

Comment: What is your hashkey? Is it fair to assume that type attribute is defined as hashkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data structure provided in the question, I assume that the attribute "type" is defined as Dynamodb data type 'STRING' (i.e. S) rather than SET (i.e. SS).

Please note that IN can be used on Dynamodb **SET** data type only.

> IN : Checks for matching elements within two sets. AttributeValueList
>   can contain one or more AttributeValue elements of type String,
>   Number, or Binary (not a set type). These attributes are compared
>   against an existing set type attribute of an item. If any elements of
>   the input set are present in the item attribute, the expression
>   evaluates to true.

If you have defined it as STRING data type, you can check the multiple values of an attribute using **"OR" condition**. Example below:-

```
var params = {
    TableName: "Movies",    
    FilterExpression: "title = :title1 OR title = :title2",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":title1": "The Big New Movie 1",
         ":title2": "The Big New Movie 2",
    }
};
```

The Dynamodb SET data type should look like:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I used the "OR" solution, works like a charm :-)